# Is there a clever way to call a type dependent extension method dynamically?

Tags: c#, linq

The code below will compile but fails at runtime.  It's provided just to give an idea of what I'm trying to do.  What I would like to do is create a method that accepts a collection of objects (effectively an "untyped" collection) and if this collect is comprised of numbers of a single type return the mean using the Average() extension method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace nnConsole {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var ints = new object[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            var dbls = new object[4] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
            Console.WriteLine(ReallyMean(ints));    
            Console.WriteLine(ReallyMean(dbls));    
            }

        static public double ReallyMean(ICollection<object> data) {
            var unique = data.Distinct();
            var types = unique.Select(x => x.GetType()).Distinct();
            if (types.Count() == 1) {
                if (types.First().IsValueType) {
                    /***********************
                     * magic here to create ddata var that will
                     * call the appropriate extension method for average */ 
                    dynamic ddata = data; // DOES NOT WORK
                    return ddata.Average();
                    }
                }
            return double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm sure I could use reflection to find the appropriate Average method and invoke it (not pretty).  Is there a shorter/cleaner/better way to do this?   I can use the latest C# and .NET runtime.

Comment: First - don't abuse `Double.NaN` for this, you can return a `Nullable<double>`, if an average makes no sense you should return no average not an invalid average. What you want to do here is essentially check if a collection has a method and if it does invoke it. This totally breaks type safety, I'd be really surprised if it's possible without reflection (with reflection - like you said it's trivial).

Comment: Your title suggests you are using [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), but your code shows no use of the keyword `this`.

Comment: @Erik, I was referring to the Average() method, not the definition of a new extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your code always returns a `double`, what you are looking for is a lambda that translates your object to a `double`:

```
var res = data.Cast<dynamic>().Average(n => (double) n);
```

Note that your program would also compile without a `Cast<dynamic>()`, but it would fail at runtime unless the underlying data type is `double`.

Comment: +1 Simple but clever. Just wondering, why the dynamic cast? You can `Select` it into an `IEnumerable` of doubles and then `Average` those.

Comment: because you can only unbox variable to the same type it was boxed from, so `(double)n` would not work when `n` is boxed `int`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek That shouldn't be the problem with `dynamic`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, that's why `dynamic` is used here. My comment was an answer to Benjamins question why it's necessary to cast to `dynamic` first.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek You probably missed `@User` notification, so your comment appears pointing to no one and so I overlooked it:)

Comment: Does this work if n is not an numeric type? (Say the collection is of bools or strings)

Answer (score 2):

Calling `ddata.Average()` will cause the dynamic runtime to try to find a proper member method on `ICollection<object>`. It doesn't do the translation to a static method call that an extension method really is underneath the syntactic sugar.

You can however rewrite it to call the extension method with normal syntax. That will allow dynamic overload resolution if there are many matching extension methods in the same class, but it will not allow automatic selection of overloads from different classes:

```
return Enumerable.Average(ddata);
```

That will bind to the correct overload of `Average` depending on the *compile time type of the `IEnumerable<T>`*. You are now using `IEnumerable<object>`, so I guess you will have to change that to `IEnumerable<dynamic>` to get it right.

Comment: This is a well-performing solution because the dynamic binding only happens once.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the type, and then cast to that type to get access to Average

```
if( types.First() == typeof(int) ){
 return unique.Cast<int>().Average();
}else{
 if( types.First() == typeof(double) ){
  return unique.Cast<double>().Average();
 }
}
```